# Why won't my program write information to the file?

Tags: java, file-io, alphabetical

I have to create a program that reads names and ID numbers from two files that are already in alphabetical order, and combine them on a third file completely in alphabetical order.. The files are organized like so...

last name, first name
ID (ex. rbb091020)
last name, first name
ID

For some reason my file reads the two files and creates a third, but it doesn't write anything to the third file.

Here's my code...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Combine_Files
{
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
{
    String filename1 = "";
    String filename2 = "";
    String combinedFileName = "";
    String response = "";
    String nextName1 = "";
    String nextName2 = "";
    String nextIDNumber1 = "";
    String nextIDNumber2 = "";
    boolean okToOverwrite = false;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the name of the first file?");
    filename1 = keyboard.nextLine();

    File file1 = new File(filename1);

    if (!file1.exists())
    {
        System.out.println(file1 + " does not exist.\nTerminating Program.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("What is the name of the second file?");
    filename2 = keyboard.nextLine();

    File file2 = new File (filename2);
    if (!file2.exists())
    {
        System.out.println(file2 + " does not exist.\nTerminating Program.");
        System.exit(0);
    }   

    System.out.println("What is the name of the file that you wish to create?");
    combinedFileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    File combinedFile = new File (combinedFileName);

    while (combinedFile.exists() && !okToOverwrite)
    {
        System.out.println("\nError, a file named " +
            combinedFileName + " already exists." +
            "\nWould you like to overwrite this file?" +  
            "\nEnter Y for Yes or N for No.");
        response = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Add input validation on response

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            okToOverwrite = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a new filename.");
            combinedFileName = keyboard.nextLine();
            combinedFile = new File(combinedFileName);
        }
    }

    if (file1.exists() && file2.exists())
    {

        Scanner list1 = new Scanner(file1);
        Scanner list2 = new Scanner(file2);
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(combinedFile);

            while (list1.hasNext() && list2.hasNext())
            {
                nextName1 = list1.nextLine();
                nextName2 = list2.nextLine();

                if(nextName1.compareToIgnoreCase(nextName2) <0)
                {
                    outputFile.print(nextName1);
                    nextName1 = list1.nextLine();
                    outputFile.print(nextName1);
                }
                else if(nextName1.compareToIgnoreCase(nextName2) >0)
                {
                    outputFile.println(nextName2);
                    nextName2 = list2.nextLine();
                    outputFile.println(nextName2);
                }
                else
                {
                    outputFile.println(nextName1);
                    nextName1 = list1.nextLine();
                    outputFile.println(nextName1);
                    outputFile.println(nextName2);
                    nextName2 = list2.nextLine();
                    outputFile.println(nextName2);
                }       
            }

            while (list1.hasNext() && !list2.hasNext())
            {
                outputFile.println(nextName1);
            }

            while (list2.hasNext() && !list1.hasNext())
            {
                outputFile.println(nextName2);
            }       
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a writer class like `PrintWriter` you need to make sure that you call the `flush()` method every time you want to print something to STDOUT or a file. So basically whenever you call any of the `PrintWriter` print methods it writes to an internal buffer, the call to `flush()` sends the buffer to the appropriate output stream.

```
        while (list1.hasNext() && list2.hasNext())
        {
            nextName1 = list1.nextLine();
            nextName2 = list2.nextLine();

            if(nextName1.compareToIgnoreCase(nextName2) <0)
            {
                outputFile.print(nextName1);
                nextName1 = list1.nextLine();
                outputFile.print(nextName1);
            }
            else if(nextName1.compareToIgnoreCase(nextName2) >0)
            {
                outputFile.println(nextName2);
                nextName2 = list2.nextLine();
                outputFile.println(nextName2);
            }
            else
            {
                outputFile.println(nextName1);
                nextName1 = list1.nextLine();
                outputFile.println(nextName1);
                outputFile.println(nextName2);
                nextName2 = list2.nextLine();
                outputFile.println(nextName2);
            }
            outputFile.flush(); // <--- flush added here       
        }

        while (list1.hasNext() && !list2.hasNext())
        {
            outputFile.println(nextName1);
            outputFile.flush(); // <--- flush added here 
        }

        while (list2.hasNext() && !list1.hasNext())
        {
            outputFile.println(nextName2);
            outputFile.flush(); // <--- flush added here 
        }
```

These calls to `flush()` should write to the file.

Comment: or simply make it `autoFlush` at invoking the constructor `PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)`

Comment: flushing issues were my first suspect, but even then, the file should be flushed when the handle is closed and the VM exits. this program has other problems.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad According to the docs the autoflush option only works for `println`, `printf`, and `format`. The poster is using `print()` mixed with `println`, so I opted for manual `flush()` calls

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That's weird! However, `close()`ing the stream at the end will buffer the data into the sink.

Comment: We haven't learned about flush() yet, and we're not suppose to use things other than what we learned.  But we have learned that things get stuck in the keyboard buffer.. Would using keyboard.nextLine(); work to flush it? Isn't there another way to flush it?

Answer (score 0):

This program has logical errors.  When I test with files of uneven length, it gets stuck in an infinite loop in one of the last two while loops, and indeed writes to the output file until the program is forcefully terminated.  If the files are of the same length, then scanner fails to read a line in one of the if/else clauses.

Comment: Also, how did you get it to write to the third file?  It only writes a blank file to my third file for some reason.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't write to the output file off the top of my head, but the behavior probably varies with input.  My two files simply contained "a" "b" "c" and "d" "e" "f" respectively, each on a line of course.  You need to debug this program, either by printing output (System.err.println("Writing xxxx to file yyy")) or via a step debugger, so you understand what the program is doing.